# OpenGL - Properly separating VAO definition from VBO and other buffers creation

Tags: c++, opengl, vao

Running a very simple draw a triangle example, I'm trying to find out which lines refer specifically to the VAO definition and which others can run apart.

Currently I'm using this code:

Buffer creation & filling:

```
TriangleVertices = new float[9]
{
     0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
};

TriangleColors = new float[12]
{
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};

glGenBuffers(1, &VertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9*sizeof(float), TriangleVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glGenBuffers(1, &ColorsBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ColorsBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 12*sizeof(float), TriangleColors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAOID);
```

VAO definition:

```
glBindVertexArray(VAOID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBuffer);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ColorsBuffer);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Drawing Loop

```
glBindVertexArray(VAOID);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

The example runs fine if in the drawing loop I include the VAO definition each frame, but it doesn't work if I define the VAO only once before starting to draw so I guess the VAO definition lacks some code.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: The code in the question was correct. The problem was coming from collision with other OpenGL calls I thought I wasn't running.

The code described below is just situational. As @derhass commented, there is no need to enable nor disable VertexAttribArray when making the draw call.

...

Old answer:

Unbindinding and disabling each element when not needed anymore fixed the problem, but I don't know if this solution can be widespread or it is specific to my environment only.

Buffer creation & filling:

```
TriangleVertices = new float[9]
{
     0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
};

TriangleColors = new float[12]
{
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};

glGenBuffers(1, &VertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9*sizeof(float), TriangleVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glGenBuffers(1, &ColorsBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ColorsBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 12*sizeof(float), TriangleColors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAOID);
```

VAO definition:

```
glBindVertexArray(VAOID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBuffer);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ColorsBuffer);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Drawing Loop

```
glBindVertexArray(VAOID);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);//not needed
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);//not needed
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);//not needed
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);//not needed
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Comment: That's not how VAOs are supposed to work. The enable state for each attribute array is part of the VAO state. it is unclear what exaclty is goiong on in your program.

Comment: @derhass You are right. I thought I was running only the triangle example, but I had another draw calls apparently colliding with this one. I'll edit the answer.